# Chromium desktop notifications desktop shortcut mode

Tags: chromium, notification

I created desktop shortcut for some websites (hipchat, slack...). When I run them from desktop, they run in their own window.

The problem is that there are no desktop notification. In slack there is a message:

[image]

After clicking this, it says:

"Your browser should now be presenting you with the option to enable notifications, probably at the top or bottom of this window. Click Enable or Allow or Yes or OK or whatever the right button is!"

But it is never presented in desktop shortcut mode.

I also allowed desktop notifications for all website in settings.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm using the web app Slacky. Each time it launches I get the enable desktop notifications message. I enable them, but the setting does not stick. Next time I open Slacky I am asked about allow notifications again.